# Where is the proper place to add a bar button item to a tool bar using storyboard?

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uitoolbar, xcode-storyboard

I have dropped a UINavigationController onto the story board and added a UIToolbar to it.  Then using storyboard I attempt to drag and drop a bar button item onto it and set its System Item property to "camera".  I don't see anything added to the toolbar. UINavigationViewController with Toolbar:

[image]

Is this the correct way to add bar button items to a toolbar using Storyboard?  I want this tool bar to appear on all view controllers attached to this navigation controller.

Answer (score 0):

Don't add a toolbar to a navigation controller. It already has one. Simply make it visible.

To add your bar button item, add it to the toolbar shown in the view controller after you mark the toolbar visible for the navigation controller.